# Windows must now restart because the [our service name] service terminated unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, crash, service, c++

as a disclaimer, I am posting this here because I have only seen comments referring to this type of behavior where people have indicated a possible problem going on with the system.  If this is not the correct place to post this, please let me know and I will post where people ask coding questions.

Having said that, I have seen many posts that say "windows must now restart because the  service terminated unexpectedly".  My situation is different in that the complaint is regarding a proprietary service that my company wrote.

My company builds machines and currently one of them, running as a release build in the field, has had some service crashes.  The proprietary service is written for this machine and has been extensively tested.  It is running on Win7 32 bit, with Windows updates turned off.  The service is written in C++ using VS2010.

On 5/28/20, between 5:05 and 5:16 pm, we had 5 different crashes of this service.  Each time the system showed the error message "Windows must now restart because the [our service name] service terminated unexpectedly".  When I look at the crash dumps, each time it is sitting at a call to sprintf() where the call stack ends at _invoke_watson().  When I first open the crash dump the error dialog for the crash says "Unhandled exception ... : An invalid parameter was passed to a C runtime function."  When I look at the sprintf call, the associated lines are:

```
char buff[10];
if (sprintf_s(buff, sizeof(buff)/sizeof(buff[0]), "%04d%02d%02d", iyear, imonth, iday) < 0)
```

These crashes are on the sprintf_s() call.  The iyear, imonth, iday are all ints, so they have to have value, but they are the values that were retrieved from a FILETIME struct (populated by a call to GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()) that was converted to a SYSTEMTIME struct (populated by a call to FileTimeToSystemTime()).  But either way, an int should be an int.

When I look in the system Event Viewer, for each crash it gives an exception code of 0xc0000417, and a system event ID of 1000 (which of course means crashed due to unknown event).

I am thrown by the fact that, other than during the span of these 13 minutes, this has never happened before and has not happened since.  I am trying to dig further into this issue, but I have no idea why a simple sprintf call would do this, and only during a span of 15 minutes.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to questions I should be "asking" of the system?  I am very adept with system work, but am not a system guy.  Any suggestions for me to continue forward would be highly appreciated.

Again, please let me know if this is the wrong place to be posting this question.

Comment: `FileTimeToSystemTime` Make sure the code checks the return value. `an int should be an int` Those are actually WORDs in SYSTEMTIME which get extended to an int when passed into `sprintf`. `5/28/20 5 pm` Is there any 3-month date arithmetic in that area of the code, by any chance? Depending on your timezone, this could be pretty close to 3 months after the start of "leap day" 2020.

Comment: Yes, it is true the return value is not being checked.  I will add that to my code change suggestions.  There is no 3-month date arithmetic in this code.  The machine is in Japan, so would that make a difference in the relationship to leap day 2020?

Comment: In that case it was just a red herring, without a 3-month offset involved somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You must be overrunning `buff`.  A format specifier such as `%04d` does not guarantee that the string placed in the buffer will be no longer than 4 characters, so if `iyear` somehow contains a value > 9999 then you will write more than the 4 characters you have allowed space for.  Similarly for `imonth` and `iday`.

So I would add some bounds checking on these values to ensure that you don't overrun your buffer.  You might also output them to some kind of debugging log if they are out of range (such as the Application Event Log) to help you track the problem down.

As for bringing down Windows when the service crashes, see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180216-00/?p=98035 (if you didn't know about that already).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Very helpful in jogging my thinking.  I had missed the fact that:
1) The information coming back in the SYSTEMTIME struct might be corrupt, and cause an increase in the length of the string produced, and 
2) From your article I realized that someone must have changed the recovery option to "Restart the Computer" instead of the original "Restart the Service" option that was set.

Comment: This sort of events is always environment / hardware related. All software advice here is usefull, but ... One question: do you catch structured exceptions in the service main? From the top `__except` we do save the minidump files. plural. they are specific to your service and are pricesless in all sorts of  "heisenbug" situations. HTH

Comment: if that is C++ why not playing it a bit safer? `char buff[0xF] {0};
if (sprintf_s(buff, 0xF, "%04d%02d%02d", iyear, imonth, iday) < 0)` .. a bit more space and zeroed before use.

Answer (score 0):

Go to services type in run
and select your name service properties
go to tab recovery
First Failur : restart the service
2nd Failur : restart the service
Subsequent Failur : restart the service